# How to test if import was successful?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, import

I'm working on a React  website written by someone else, and it contains the lines:

```
import "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
import "popper.js/dist/popper.min"
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
```

The site it throwing a 404 error, and I want to test whether these three imports are the cause. Is there a way to modify the code to check if each import returned something non-falsy?

Comment: When you build the site and search for those fils you should be able to fin the imports. Do you have a link to the live site? Usually scripts like this wont let the site throw 404 errors.

Comment: A failed import wouldn't cause an entire site to be 404. Please provide more information about the error.

Comment: I agree with the two previous comments. But how to check if the import like above was actually successful?